# Generating Sets via recursion - Language and strings (cs/logic)

Tags: string, math, logic, computer-science

This is a general logic question, common to most introductory language and machines courses. However I've searched the internet and the forums for any help on this, but I cant seem to find a topic that details what the successive sets will contain. Here is an example question: (I have many HW problems like this, I just don't know where to start)

Let L be the language over {a,b} generated by the following recursive definition
basis: λ ∈ L
recursive step: If w ∈ L then awbb is in L.
closure: A string w ∈ L only if it can be obtained from the basis set by a finite number
of applications of the recursive step.
Part a. Give the sets L1; L2; and L3 generated by the recursive definition. Note that L0 = λ

I get that The alphabet is {a,b}, Lo = the empty string, and if a string w is contained in L, then awbb is in L. But what does that mean for the next couple sets?

I think L1 = {λ ,awbb} and then L2={λ , awbb, aawbbwbb}?

Any help you could offer on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have there is also often called an *inductive definition*. The defined set is the smallest fixpoint of this definition (or, in "laymens' terms", the smallest set that fulfills the given criteria). Note that the latter is vitally important (you phrased it as "finally many applications"), otherwise many sets conform to the "definition".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you're misinterpreting what the rule

> If w ∈ L, then awbb ∈ L

means.  This doesn't mean that the literal string "awbb" is in L.  Instead, it means that if you have some string w ∈ L, you can substitute that string w into the string awbb and that resulting string will be in L.  For example, if ab ∈ L, then aabbb ∈ L as well.

Using this, try constructing the sets L<sub>1</sub> and L<sub>2</sub> again.  I think that you'll spot an immediate pattern once you've built up the first few sets.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  For your example, if w=ab then L1= {λ, aabbb} and L2={ {λ, aabbb, aababbb} etc, puting ab into the middle of the previous string. So in general L1={λ, awbb} and L2={λ, awwbb} and so forth? Or am I missing your point entirely?

Comment: @user1193839- I think you're missing my point entirely. :-)  Think of w as a placeholder.  If you have a string in the set L, then you can take that string and plug it in to the spot where w normally would be in the string.  So, for example, if you know that lambda is in L, after one application of the rules you would get that abb is also in L, since if you substitute lambda for w in awbb you get abb.  If you want to construct L2, try substituting abb for w in the string awbb and see what new string results.

Comment: ohhh. Ok I think i have this now. L2 = a[w]bb -> w = abb where w is the value gathered from the previous recursive step.  L2 generates the string aabbbb, and L3 generates aaabbbbbb. Basically you just keep inserting the string from the previous step in between a and bb.

Comment: One more quick question, do the next sets contain all of the previous values as well? For example is L2={λ,abb,aabbbb} or does the set only contain the value generated on that recursive step?

Comment: @user1193839- Yes, they should.  Each set is the result of starting with the previous set, then adding to that set the result of applying the rule to each member of the previous set.

Comment: You just saved me a ton of time. You are awesome!